# ActionBarCompat & Transparency

Tags: android, android-actionbar-compat

I would like to make the ActionBar in the support library fully transparent, however, it seems that changing the background drawable won't suffice since the backgrounds stack. If you put a semi-transparent background you end up with the default background behind it.

Does anyone know a way to remove that background?

This is what happens:

[image: Actionbar]

The code for the background drawable:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#66336688"/>
</shape>
```

As you can see, the drawable has a transparent blue that overlaps with the default gray background.

Comment: [Look at this](http://cyrilmottier.com/2013/05/24/pushing-the-actionbar-to-the-next-level/)

Comment: Thanks Ahmad, your link was very useful. I works on newer versions of the SDK, but below API level 11 it crashes... I willl update my answer if I manage to make it work

Comment: use Actionbar Sherlock for previous versions it provide backward compatibility of actionbar.

Comment: @MuhammadAamirALi Sherlock will be deprecated soon, it is not a good a idea for new projects.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution messing around with the SDK.
It seems that it is pretty simple, you need to do 3 things:

- Create a background drawable as shown on my question.
- Create an ActionBar style like so:

  ```
  <!-- Application theme. -->
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
      <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

      <!-- Support library compatibility -->
      <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
  </style>

  <!-- ACTION BAR STYLES -->
  <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
      <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
      <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>

      <!-- Support library compatibility -->
      <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
      <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
  </style>
  ```
- Use the Window feature for ActionBar overlay using the Support method (ignore Eclipse's warning regarding API level for the constant; I used the SuppressLint annotation to remove the warning):

  ```
  @SuppressLint("InlinedApi") @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);}
  ```

Comment: `supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);` worked for me. Thanks

Comment: the code doesn't work without your comment @zackygaurav, thank you

Answer (score 6):

ChristianGuerrero answer is great but you should directly put the item:

```
<item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
```

inside the AppTheme style. Then you don't have to add anything in your onCreate method.